# HTML META CHARACTER SET

Tags: html

If we are not use any META tag in the HTML program then what encoding method it has take in default?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this depended on the browser.

Comment: Why the SHOUTING in the title?

Answer (score 0):

the browser settings, whose default again could depend on which country you are in and which language is chosen as the language in your OS at the time of installation.